# I don't get the use of axis(1:2) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am in front of the following (modified) matlab code :

```
figure(3);
subplot(2,3,2);
axises=axis;
center = [mean(axises(1:2)),mean(axises(3:4))]'
```

my problem is :

- Why did he use `axises` and not keep using `axis` ?
- What does `axises(1:2)` do ?

I have checked the [axis documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html?refresh=true), but there is no mention to something like `1:2` or `3:4` ?

Please, this will an easy question for an expert in matlab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `axis` does different things whether you pass an argument or not. Without any parameters, it returns the current axis bounds (see the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#outputarg_lim)), whereas with parameters, it tries to set the current axis to a specified range ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#inputarg_limits)).

`axises = axis` stores the current axis bounds in `axises`, which you can then extract elements from. `axises(1:2)` gets the first two elements of axis (which are `[xmin xmax]`), and `axises(3:4)` gets the 3rd and 4th elements (which are `[ymin ymax]`). The result of `mean(axises(1:2))` is then the average of `xmin` and `xmax`, which is what you'd expect `center(1)` to be. Same with the `y` component.

You can't use `axis(1:2)` instead of `axises(1:2)`, because matlab will interpret this as attempting to call the function `axis` with argument `1:2` rather than extracting the first two elements of the current axis

**Example:**

```
>> axis(1:2)
```

> Error using axis>LocSetLimits (line 227)
>   Vector must have 4, 6, or 8 elements.
>
> Error in axis (line 93)
>                   LocSetLimits(ax(j),cur_arg);

```
>> axises = axis;
>> axises(1:2)

ans =

 0    10
```

Comment: Yeah. See the case `lim = axis` in the documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html. more detail in the section here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#outputarg_lim

Comment: You shall edit your answer for adding valuable information instead of using comments. +1 already esp for the last point :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit :). My comment here was in response to a now deleted comment from the OP asking if there was info in the documentation

Comment: I saw that,, anyways you could add it now, as this might help not only the OP but also other readers

Answer (score 0):

1. `axises = axis` is assigning the output of the `axis` to a variable called `axises`... it's mostly cosmetic
2. Your real question is what does `axis` do in this context.  It's a 4 element vector that returns the minimum and maximum `x` values and the minimum and maximum `y` values of the current axes seen in your figure.  The first two elements, `axises(1:2)`, stores the min and max `x` and the last two elements, `axises(3:4)`, store the min and max `y`.  Therefore, what your `center` code is doing is finding the average of both the `x`, `mean(axises(1:2))` and `y`, `mean(axises(3:4))` values to find the middle point of the `x` and `y` axes.